# extract value from nested json in apache nifi

Tags: java, json, regex, apache-nifi, jolt

i have escaped json dataflow (that drives from ConvertAvroToJSON processor) like this:

```
{"data": "{\"created_at\":\"Sun Sep 24 11:10:52 +0000 2017\"}"}
```

and i just need "json" value, like this[*after unescapeJson*]:

```
{"created_at":"Sun Sep 24 11:10:52 +0000 2017"}
```

i tried JoltTransformJSON and EvaluateJsonPath solutions but both of them return me this, with *{"* and *"}* at begining and end tail of it :

```
{"{"created_at":"Sun Sep 24 11:10:52 +0000 2017"}"}
```

what should i do?

**Jolt Spec:**

> [{   "operation": "shift",   "spec": {
>       "data": {
>         "*": "&"
>       }   } }]

**EvaluateJsonPath:**

> $..*

Answer (score 2):

use  `EvaluateJsonPath` with  `$.data` expression

if you have `{"data": "{\"created_at\":\"Sun Sep 24 11:10:52 +0000 2017\"}"}` in the content of your flowfile

it will replace the content with the following data:

`{"created_at":"Sun Sep 24 11:10:52 +0000 2017"}`

here are all the parameters of the processor

[image]

Comment: not works, same result `[
  "{\"created_at\":\"Sun Sep 24 11:10:52 +0000 2017\"}"
]`

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 steps. First, extract inner json to your flow content. After that you can access json attributes from this json flow content.

**First Step:**
[image: First Step]

**Second Step**
[image: Second Step]

**Flow View**

[image: Flow view of this actions]